# Why is my card overlapping the fixed nav when I hover it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, nav

I have a problem when I hover my article with `class="card"` name inside my div `class="container"`, it looks like the article overlaps the nav. How do I fix this without removing my transform scale in `.card:hover`? I want to make it without overlapping with the nav when I hover over it.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};


var navbar = document.querySelector(".myNav");


var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;


function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
* {
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-image: url('/Website/Images/SPY_X_FAMILY.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 200vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header-container {
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.885;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #FFA1C9;
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav {
  background-color: #F94892;
  margin: 0 50px 50px 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav:hover {
  transform: scale(1.005);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav li {
  color: rgb(227, 118, 118);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul {
  margin-top: 0;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
  font-size: 20px;
}

.myHeader {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFC4C4;
  margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 12px;
}

header h1>img {
  width: 42%;
}

nav li {
  margin: 0;
}

nav a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
}

nav a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 15px;
  background: rgb(182, 1, 32);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.card {
  background-color: #FBE5E5;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 1.25em;
  padding: 1.25em;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.0025);
  transition: 0.2s;
  position: relative;
}

.content-container>h2 {
  margin: 10px;
}


/* text font-size */

h2 {
  font-size: 2.25em;
  color: rgb(212, 27, 58);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 20px;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: F94892;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: rgb(212, 27, 58);
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}


/* image */

.image-style {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 300%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}


/* sticky navbar */

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transform: scale(1.0025);
}

.sticky li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 50px;
}


/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the navigation bar gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */

.sticky+nav {
  padding-top: 60px;
}


/* profile things */

.card-v2 {
  background-color: #FBE5E5;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 1.25em;
  padding: 1.25em;
}

.card-v2:hover {
  transform: scale(1.0025);
  transition: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 5px #F94892;
}

.profile {
  background-color: #FFA1C9;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  width: 25%
}

.profile img {
  width: 200px;
}

.profile header {
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-head {
  display: inline;
}

#aside {
  background-color: #FFA1C9;
  margin: 0;
}

.card-v3 {
  background-color: #FFC4C4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 1.25em;
  padding: 1.25em;
}

.card-v3:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 8px #efd6d6;
}


/* table */

.table-style {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>My Problem</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header-container header-scroll">
    <div class="myHeader">
      <h1>
        <img src="/Website/Images/Spy_×_Family_logo.png" alt="header">
      </h1>
    </div>
    <nav class="myNav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#about'>About<a/></li>
                  <li><a href='#other'>Other</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <article id="home" class="content-container-column card ">
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
        <img src="/Website/Images/3774625814.jpg" class="image-style" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum architecto culpa ab enim tempora atque corporis nam rem, exercitationem quasi cumque et quam quisquam odio, labore fugit molestias, quo quod?</p>
        <p>Lorem</p>
        <h3>Header 3</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto inventore nisi provident quasi reiciendis odit reprehenderit ut non, voluptatum perspiciatis blanditiis illo a! Rem, recusandae ab commodi provident ex praesentium.</p>

      </article>
      <article id="about" class="card content-container-column">
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
        <img src="/Website/Images/357396304.jpg" class="image-style" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi expedita soluta nihil, praesentium perferendis cum rerum similique ab? Natus saepe molestias reiciendis voluptas voluptatibus consectetur adipisci praesentium asperiores deleniti
          odio.</p>
      </article>
      <article id="other" class="card content-container-column">
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
        <img src="/Website/Images/spy-x-family-yor-forger.gif" class="image-style" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores tempora doloribus dicta quibusdam, corrupti quam maiores laboriosam quo voluptatum autem ea ad quaerat id suscipit magnam unde cupiditate, voluptates harum.</p>
      </article>
    </div>

    <aside id="aside" class="profile">
      <article class="card-v2">
        <header class="profile-head">
          <h2>About Me</h2>
          <figure class="card-v3">
            <img src="/Website/Images/Dwiki_Yulian.jpg" alt="">
          </figure>
        </header>
        <section>
          <table class="table-style">
            <tr>
              <th>Name:</th>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Tempat, tanggal lahir:</th>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Alamat:</th>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Agama:</th>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

            </tr>
          </table>
        </section>

      </article>
    </aside>

  </main>

  <script src="muscle.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

If anything is missing from the snippet, you can check my jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dwiki/tcp873qu/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're experiencing is something referred to as [The Stacking Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) which, if you think about it from a top-down perspective, is how elements are rendered in the browser. To solve this, you can set the parent element -- in this case the `header-container` -- to `position: relative;` and give it a z-index of 1 to override the default of 0. That will elevate it above the card which is using the default of 0 even when hovered.

Here's another good explanation for it as well: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/stacking-contexts/

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};


var navbar = document.querySelector(".myNav");


var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;


function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
* {
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-image: url('/Website/Images/SPY_X_FAMILY.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 200vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header-container {
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.885;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #FFA1C9;
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav {
  background-color: #F94892;
  margin: 0 50px 50px 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav:hover {
  transform: scale(1.005);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav li {
  color: rgb(227, 118, 118);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav ul {
  margin-top: 0;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
  font-size: 20px;
}

.myHeader {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFC4C4;
  margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 12px;
}

header h1>img {
  width: 42%;
}

nav li {
  margin: 0;
}

nav a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  font-family: 'Quicksand';
}

nav a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 15px;
  background: rgb(182, 1, 32);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.card {
  background-color: #FBE5E5;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 1.25em;
  padding: 1.25em;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.0025);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.content-container>h2 {
  margin: 10px;
}


/* text font-size */

h2 {
  font-size: 2.25em;
  color: rgb(212, 27, 58);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 20px;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: F94892;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: rgb(212, 27, 58);
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}


/* image */

.image-style {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 300%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}


/* sticky navbar */

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transform: scale(1.0025);
  z-index: 1;
}

.sticky li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 50px;
}


/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the navigation bar gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */

.sticky+nav {
  padding-top: 60px;
}


/* profile things */

.card-v2 {
  background-color: #FBE5E5;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 1.25em;
  padding: 1.25em;
  z-index: 0;
}

.card-v2:hover {
  transform: scale(1.0025);
  transition: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 5px #F94892;
}

.profile {
  background-color: #FFA1C9;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  width: 25%
}

.profile img {
  width: 200px;
}

.profile header {
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-head {
  display: inline;
}

#aside {
  background-color: #FFA1C9;
  margin: 0;
}

.card-v3 {
  background-color: #FFC4C4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 1.25em;
  padding: 1.25em;
  z-index: 0;
}

.card-v3:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 8px #efd6d6;
}


/* table */

.table-style {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>My Problem</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header-container header-scroll">
    <div class="myHeader">
      <h1>
        <img src="/Website/Images/Spy_×_Family_logo.png" alt="header">
      </h1>
    </div>
    <nav class="myNav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#about'>About</a>a></li>
        <li><a href='#other'>Other</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <article id="home" class="content-container-column card ">
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
        <img src="/Website/Images/3774625814.jpg" class="image-style" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum architecto culpa ab enim tempora atque corporis nam rem, exercitationem quasi cumque et quam quisquam odio, labore fugit molestias, quo quod?</p>
        <p>Lorem</p>
        <h3>Header 3</h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto inventore nisi provident quasi reiciendis odit reprehenderit ut non, voluptatum perspiciatis blanditiis illo a! Rem, recusandae ab commodi provident ex praesentium.</p>

      </article>
      <article id="about" class="card content-container-column">
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
        <img src="/Website/Images/357396304.jpg" class="image-style" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi expedita soluta nihil, praesentium perferendis cum rerum similique ab? Natus saepe molestias reiciendis voluptas voluptatibus consectetur adipisci praesentium asperiores deleniti
          odio.
        </p>
      </article>
      <article id="other" class="card content-container-column">
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
        <img src="/Website/Images/spy-x-family-yor-forger.gif" class="image-style" alt="">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores tempora doloribus dicta quibusdam, corrupti quam maiores laboriosam quo voluptatum autem ea ad quaerat id suscipit magnam unde cupiditate, voluptates harum.</p>
      </article>
    </div>

    <aside id="aside" class="profile">
      <article class="card-v2">
        <header class="profile-head">
          <h2>About Me</h2>
          <figure class="card-v3">
            <img src="/Website/Images/Dwiki_Yulian.jpg" alt="">
          </figure>
        </header>
        <section>
          <table class="table-style">
            <tr>
              <th>Name:</th>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Tempat, tanggal lahir:</th>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Alamat:</th>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Agama:</th>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

            </tr>
          </table>
        </section>

      </article>
    </aside>

  </main>

  <script src="muscle.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set the z-index of the nav to 100

```
nav {
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't work